# Merging multiple dictionary in python with same keys, if key not common append 0 to the value

Tags: python

Can someone give me advise how to merge two dictionaries ( Beginner here) for my case . For the keys common, I want to append the values. If key is there in one and not the other dictionary, I want to add 0 as value in the merged dictionary .

```
d1 = {'David': '5.5', 'John': '1.0', 'Tim' : '2' }
d2 = {'David': '42.5', 'John': '37.0'}
```

Desired output

```
d3 = {'David' : ['5.5', '42.5'], 'John' : ['1.0', '37'], 'Tim' : ['2','0']}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate available keys through the set union of keys of the two dicts and for each key, output the respective values of the two dicts with the `dict.get` method, with `0` as a default value:

```
{k: [d.get(k, '0') for d in (d1, d2)] for k in d1.keys() | d2.keys()}
```

This returns:

```
{'David': ['5.5', '42.5'], 'John': ['1.0', '37.0'], 'Tim': ['2', '0']}
```